# Why aren't the enderman spawning in the only possible location?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm in the end, in a space in the void, and near the bottom, at y = 2, where I'm not close to any specific piece of land where enderman can spawn. All spawnable places have been covered with slabs or lighting, all, but the four endstone blocks in front of me, in the enclosed, roofless 2x2 area.

Still, even with that area being the only one spawnable, no enderman are spawning at all. I've tried going away and coming back, I know they won't spawn if I'm already here, but no matter the case they don't spawn.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried going away and coming back

How much? Keep in mind that mobs follow this rule to spawn:

[image]

Since you only have a 2x2 spawnable area, it's easy to miss the correct distance to make them spawn. You need to be at least 24 blocks away, but if you exceed 32 blocks they can still despawn.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are preventing spawning:

1. The light level is over 7
2. Due to the slab, there is less than 3 blocks of air above it preventing enderman from spawning.
3. Not completely sure: In the end enderman can only spawn on end stone but can teleport to other blocks.

Hope this helped: